# EF and customer data separation

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework

Is it possible to build an ASP.NET website using EF where each customer logging in has separately stored data? We have customers demanding that their data won’t be stored in the same tables as other customers’ data.

I’ve read that EF can’t work with several databases but is it possible to switch database at runtime depending on input parameters? I have a feeling it won’t be possible since the migration features are tightly connected to the database being used, but I'm not sure.

One solution could be to have a separate website deployment and database for each customer. They’ll get separate domains to access but that’s not a problem. But this solution feels a bit clumsy if you’re having many customers, especially with deployment and future upgrades.

Am I missing some smart ways of solving this or is this a very tricky issue?

Comment: This is called multi-tenant. It is expected that EF will support this in the (near?) future because it is a great issue with Azure databases. An alternative is database schema per tenant. You should be able to find threads about that.

Comment: Very interesting. I have to do some more reading on that.

Comment: @GertArnold I don't think he needs multi-tenant here - if he wishes to switch entire database - then you don't have two structures, models or DbContext-s using the same Db - and sharing same __MigrationHistory. i.e. he just needs to switch connections as I understand it.

Comment: @NSGaga Yes, that's the question, but sometimes it helps to give some reference terminology.

Comment: @GertArnold Thanks for broadening my reference terminology :-) It wasn't exactly what I needed here but it's indeed interesting when EF will support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**is structure (of the db) the same ?**

if so you could switch connections - not w/o issues though, but should work. For details on how that should be done check the long discussion we've had here (and linked previous questions etc.)...

[Code first custom connection string and migrations without using IDbContextFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926897/code-first-custom-connection-string-and-migrations-without-using-idbcontextfacto/15938194#15938194)

Comment: Yes, structure is the same for all customers. Interesting discussion on the other thread. It seems to be a bit unstable though, or? One main concern I have is how migrations will work with several databases. If I understood your thread correctly it did work, right? When will the migration actually run for an individual customer? Will it be when that specific customer logs-in and his/her database is accessed for the first time since the system was upgraded?

Comment: yes it does work - and I think it's stable enough. The only problem is if you switch 'connection'/customer too often, all connections will remain open, which may or may not be a problem. Since you're running in a web scenario, you'll open 'one customer' at the time as I understand so shouldn't worry about it, I think (fast). Migration happens on first 'access to the structure'/entities (i.e. somewhere inside `using(...DbContext())` stuff. And you cannot `log in` user (unless using another db for accounts) until you create the Db, ie migrate it. You should just switch connections per your scen.

Comment: just to add - if your db-s are the same - then underlying EF has no problems with it (migrations, history table, structure, entities are all fine). The only issue EF has is that it 'caches' connections for the AppDomain (even though declaratively it doesn't, but they have a bug there I think) - so you have to 'reinitialize' your migration initializer each time a new connection (or `DbContext` with new conn.) is activated - and you can easily do that via some static variable like I did. And all previous 'migrators' and connections are still there. Again it may not be a problem for you at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I think this is what I need. I understand that the caching of the connection might be an issue but I guess I have to do some testing there myself.